# Can any tell me how add two needles in Gauge graph Using Google charts

Tags: google-visualization

I want to display two values in a single gauge graph using two needles. How can I do that. 
Can any one please suggest me of doing it.

I have tried with following code But I am not success full.

And I got this following error.

```
GET http://5.39.186.164/%7B%22cols%22:[%7B%22label%22:%22Q7%22,%22type%22:%22nu…r%22%7D],%22rows%22:[%7B%22c%22:[%7B%22v%22:43%7D,%7B%22v%22:21%7D]%7D]%7D 404 (Not Found)
```

```js
<!--Load the AJAX API -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['gauge']});
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var gauge;
    var gaugeData;
    var gaugeOptions;
    function drawGauge() {
        //var response = '<?php echo json_encode($response); ?>';     alert(' hi ' + response);            
        //var obj = eval ("(" + response + ")");  
        $.getJSON('<?php echo json_encode($response); ?>', function(json) {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
             data.addColumn('string', 'Label');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
               for (x in json) {
                data.addRow([x, json[x]]);
            }



      //gaugeData = new  google.visualization.DataTable(response);

      gauge = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('gauge'));
      gaugeOptions = {
           width: 2000,
        height: 150,
        greenFrom: 0,
        greenTo: 50,
        redFrom: 75,
        redTo: 100,
        yellowFrom:50,
        yellowTo: 75,
        minorTicks: 5
      };
      gauge.draw(gaugeData, gaugeOptions);
        //chart.draw(data, options);
        });
    }


    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['gauge'], callback: drawGauge});
```

Comment: There are two parts to this: first off, why are you putting a JSON string in the URL of jQuery's `getJSON` method?  Second, do you want a single Gauge with two needles or multiple gauges?  Having a single Gauge with 2 needles is not supported.

Comment: Hi I want Having a single Gauge with 2 needles. and Ho ok sorry I kept by mistakenly the JSON string I was trying in different ways.AND can you tell me How can I do single Gauge with 2 needles

Comment: As I said, one Gauge with two needles is not supported.  You can have multiple Gauges (like the example on the [documentation page](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/gauge)) if you need to display more than one data point.

Comment: Is there any other method I can do it.

Comment: If you stacked two gauges on top of each other with the same scale, and then deleted all of the svg elements of the chart so that it was transparent, you would be able to see two needles. Though for the love of all that is holy, what would it accomplish? One needle is red, one is green, is everything okay or not? You should rethink from first principles, not create a complex disastrous new chart!